# extern "C" static array function parameter

Tags: c++, c, c99, c11

I would like to interface with a C library I've written from a C++ program. The C library is written using modern C, and has made use of the `static` array specifier to show the minimum length of an array, or that a pointer cannot be `NULL`.

When I try to write a program that interfaces with an `extern "C"` function using this feature I get the following message:

> error: static array size is a C99 feature, not permitted in C++

Is it not possible to interface with this C library? Will I have to modify the C library, or is there an alternative available?

Here's an example program that causes the error:

```
// foo.h

#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo(int i[static 1]);

#endif //FOO_H
```

```
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int i[static 1]) {
    printf("%i", i[0]);
}
```

```
// main.cpp

extern "C"
{
    void foo(int i[static 1]);
}

int main() {
    int i[] = {1};
    foo(i);
}
```

Comment: You can't magically make a C++ Compiler understand VLAs. `extern "C"` only specifies a language binding, not magically teaches a C++ Compiler the language referred to.

Comment: @J.Doe I don't think this is a VLA. the `static` in the array index is a hint to the compiler that the array this pointer points to is at LEAST that size, and a requirement to any programmer calling the function that the array they're sending must be at least that size. I'm curious what its function signature looks like when compiled.

Comment: @John You are right. Forget me mentioning VLAs. It doesn't tell the C++ Compiler about what a static array size is.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the function signature in C is just an unmangled name. `extern C` means, "Hey, don't mangle this name. This is the function signature as is". You shouldn't be actually DEFINING the function in the `extern "C"` block, right? You're just supposed to link to it? So you'd write `extern "C" { void foo(int i[]); }` and make sure you link with the library. I don't do a lot (or any at all) interfacing with C libraries. I've just seen it in the past.

Comment: I was just putting the definition in the `extern` block for testing, I'm not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: If you define the function in the `extern "C"` block AND link to a C library that contains the same function signature, you *should* (I am NOT a compiler expert) get an error about multiple definitions found of function "foo" or something like that.

Comment: I'm really hoping someone who knows more than me on this chimes in. I'm half guessing at a lot of this based on snippets I've seen in the past. Please take my comments with a grain of salt.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Comment: No luck. Same error.

Comment: Same error? My suggestion OMITS the `static` keyword though. You shouldn't get that error at all.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks. That did it, guess I'll put the answer below.

Comment: I'll write up an answer. There are some caveats to this. For one, the C compiler that created the library may have made some optimizations to the code EXPECTING that all arrays passed in are at least the given size. For example, possibly loop unrolling up to size N? Who knows. If the compiled code requires the array to be that size, and you pass something not large enough, that type safety is busted. So you have to be really careful when calling the function. I'm not sure how to ensure that safety.

Comment: Thanks! I will also amend my question with the definition outside of the `extern` block.

Comment: @John although in the case of `static 1` specifically, it's redundant as Standard C and C++ do not support zero-sized arrays anyway. Perhaps this is supposed to indicate "pointer should not be a null pointer"

Comment: @M.M Yes, it specifies that the item cannot be `NULL`. So it can be used for pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extern "C"` indicates to the C++ compiler that the function name should not be mangled. Since you're linking against an external library, the expectation is that the external library has a function (and only one function) called `foo`. The `static` keyword in C99 and onward in an array size tells the compiler that "this array will be at least this size", which may allow the compiler to make certain optimizations (I don't know what optimizations these could be, but consider that it could possibly do loop unrolling up to `N = 4`, where you declared `void foo(int i[static 5]);` If you pass an array that is not at LEAST this size, you could have a bad time.

The immediate solution is just that we need to tell the C++ compiler:

1. There is a function called `foo`
2. It takes an `int *` as a parameter

```
extern "C"
{
    void foo(int i[]);
}
```

But we lose the information to anyone using this in the C++ program that this function MUST be at least size N (which is what the `static` keyword in the array size meant). I can't think of a good way to force a compile-time check on this except possibly through some type templated wrapper function:

```
#include <cstddef>

extern "C"
{
    void foo(int i[]);
}

template <std::size_t N>
void c_foo(int i[N])
{
    static_assert(N >= 5);
    foo(i);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int b[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    c_foo<5>(a); // this will be fine
    c_foo<4>(b); // this will raise a compile-time error
}
```

To be extra safe, I'd put the function prototypes for your `c_foo` functions and any "safe" `extern "C"` prototypes in one `c_library_interface.h` file, and the function definitions for your `c_foo` functions and any "unsafe" `extern "C"` prototypes in another `c_library_interface_unsafe.cpp` file. That way, as long as you don't include the unsafe file in your main C++ files, you should only be able to interface with the `static` array size functions through the templates, which will do some size checking.

Comment: From what I know, compilers don't actually implement `[ static n]` any different from ordinary pointers and this C99 feature was rather misguided. In order to actually increase type safety at compile-time, the compiler would need to see the function declaration, the function call and a static size array, all inside the same translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

(This is additional information to the answer by John)

The C header is not correct in C++ so you will have to modify it .

Probably the intent of `[static 1]` is to indicate that the function should not be called with a null pointer. There's no standard way to indicate this in both languages and the author's choice is not compatible with C++.

Some major compilers support `__attribute__((nonnull))` in both languages, either as a postfix to each parameter, or as a prefix to the function which then applies to all pointer parameters.

In my personalized header I define a preprocessor macro that expands to the equivalent syntax for each compiler , or blank for compilers that don't support it.

Bear in mind that there's no requirement for a compiler to enforce the behaviour and there will certainly be cases where it doesn't (e.g. passing on a received pointer that it doesn't know anything about).

So IMHO with the current state of compiler attitudes towards this feature (be it the attribute or the `static 1`) , this should be viewed as a form of user documentation.

I actually have decided not to use it in my own code, after some experimentation:  using this attribute will cause the compiler to optimize out any null-pointer checks in the function body, which introduces the possibility of runtime errors since there is no effective prevention of null pointers being passed. To make the feature usable, the compiler would also have to issue diagnostics any time the function is called and the compiler cannot guarantee the argument is non-null. (Which is an option I would like to see in compilers, but so far as I know, doesn't exist yet).

Comment: "So IMHO with the current state of compiler attitudes towards this feature (be it the attribute or the static 1) , this should be viewed as a form of user documentation." This is my take too, I have yet to see a compiler generating any different code upon spotting `[static n]`.

Comment: @Lundin i've seen gcc remove null pointer checks for `__attribute__((nonnull))` , haven't checked for `[static 1]` but it seems reasonable to assume they might do it in future if they don't already

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case currently: https://godbolt.org/z/w2fQah. The attribute nonnull works, static doesn't. However, clang gives identical machine code for both examples. So it seems that at least clang does implement this.